# Ipe unintentional image crop

Tags: image

I utilize the open-source software [Ipe](https://ipe.otfried.org/) to edit and create images. I try to create an image of a triangle in front of a great circle as depicted below. As you can see, the right spike is cut off. You can try yourself:

1. Firstly, create a filled circle;
2. Then, a line with forward arrow;
3. Next item is to hide the arrow tail;
4. Move the arrow until it is tangent to the circle;
5. Export it as a PNG image.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. Thank you.

Comment: No code required. There is only a workflow on a open source software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if there is no code, it cannot be about programming and therefore doesn't belong on SO. I'm happy to consider voting to re-open if I have misunderstood.

Comment: It is really only use the program and try to reproduce the enummerated steps I listed, like a programming task.

Comment: I solved the issue, YEAH! I just added a box around the desired image and it did not crop the corner anymore...